# The limit for First-Order Derivative of Standard Normal Hazard Rate

Tags: limits, statistics, normal-distribution

Let $h(x) = \frac{\phi(x)}{1-\Phi(x)}$ be the hazard rate function of standard normal distribution and $h'(x)$ be its first-order derivative.

May I ask whether there exists $\lim_{x \rightarrow \infty} h'(x)$?

Comment: [WA gives](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input?i=series+D%5B1%2FSqrt%5B2+Pi%5D+*+Exp%5B-z%5E2%2F2%5D%2F%281%2F2+*+Erfc%5Bz%2FSqrt%5B2%5D%5D%29%2Cz%5D+point+z%3D%2BInfinity) $h'(z)=1-z^{-2}+6z^{-4}+O(z^{-6})$.

Comment: Does this mean that the limit converges to 1?

Comment: @HyunsukBaek Yes, the series conerges to 1 for $x\to \infty$.